# Error 22 error C2228: left of '.size' must have class/struct/union

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors

I know there are a bunch of duplicates of this, but none of the answers seem to be helping.

```
class Vertex 
{
public:
    string           name;   // Vertex name
    vector<Vertex *>  adj;   // Adjacent vertices
    int              dist;   // Cost
    Vertex          *path;   // Previous vertex on shortest path
    bool          visited;

    Vertex( const string & nm ) : name( nm )
      { reset( ); }

    void reset( )
      { dist = INFINITY; path = NULL; }
};

void Graph::explore(Vertex *v)
{
    //error for v.visited
    //error for anything where 'v' is referenced.
    v.visited = true;
    int total;

    for(int i = 0; i < v.adj.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << v.adj.name << " to ";
        if (!v.visited)
        {
            explore(v.adj[i]);
        }   
    } 
}
```

I can't pinpoint the cause of the error after reading the other posts. (I am new to c++).
Can anyone else see anything? The error is within other methods as well.

Comment: `std::vector` doensn't even have a `name` member. The real fix for your code is to remove all the pointers.

Comment: Alright.. assume everything works, except for what I said. I'd rather not post the whole everything if I don't have to. The only issue was when I added this method and others. Other than that, it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v` is a pointer, so you need to use the pointer member access operator (`->`) instead of the object member access operator (`.`).

```
void Graph::explore(Vertex *v)
{
    v->visited = true;
    int total;

    for(int i = 0; i < v->adj.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << v->name << " to "; // this should be v->name,
                                   // not v->adj.name
        if (!v->visited)
        {
            explore(v->adj[i]);
        }   
    } 
}
```

Comment: Need to change explore(v->adj[i]) to explore(v->adj + i) or explore(& (v->adj[i]) ) because it is a pointer.

Comment: @DanielV `adj` has type `vector<Vertex *>` and there's no `operator +` defined for this type, so `v->adj + i` is not defined.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I've been trying to figure out what exactly -> means.. Would it be relevant enough to give a quick explanation as to what it really does? Is it the same as '.' then, just for pointers?

Answer (score -1):

```
void Graph::explore(Vertex *v)
```

defines v as a pointer to a vertex.  You can reference it's members with v->member. I recommend changing the definition to:

```
void Graph::explore(Vertex &v)
```

which defines v as a vertex (using a reference), it's just an optimization so that the entire data structure isn't stacked when the function is called.  Then you can access v's members as v.member

An alternative solution (not recommended, using a reference is better) is

```
void Graph::explore(Vertex *v)
{
    //error for v.visited
    //error for anything where 'v' is referenced.
    v->visited = true;
    int total;

    for(int i = 0; i < v->adj.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << v->adj.name << " to ";
        if (!v->visited)
        {
            explore(& (v->adj[i]) );
        }   
    } 
}
```

Which keeps v defined as a pointer to a vertex, but it changes the member access and recursion call to reflect this.

Comment: `v->adj[i]` is a pointer to `Vertex` already, see the declaration of `adj`: `vector<Vertex *>  adj`

Comment: *it's just an optimization so that the entire data structure isn't stacked when the function is called* this is **utterly wrong**, at low level, pointers and references are most of the times indistinguishable in terms of being a parameter for a function call.

Comment: I meant void function(datatype& X) is an optimization for void function(datatype X).  He said he was new, I don't think going into all the details of references is necessary here.

Comment: he originally defined `explore` taking a pointer, what's absolutely fine for what matters in terms of avoiding unnecessary copies, so there's no point in recommending the signature to be changed to accept a reference instead, justifying this advice based on code performance optimization.